# Arranging 11 letters in a row so that every Y lies between two X's (not necessarily adjacent)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can the 11 letters ABCDEFXXXYY be arranged in a row so that every Y lies between two X's (not necessarily adjacent)?

The answer is $3\binom{11}56!$ – my working:
$$\begin{align} ... X Y X Y X ... \end{align}$$
so there will be 6 gaps between the X's and Y's to insert the remaining distinct letters. This is where I am stuck. I know that there are $6!$ ways to arrange the remaining 6 distinct letters, but how did the $3$ and $\binom{11}5$ come about? Is my idea/approach wrong?

Comment: What do you mean, every Y lies between two X's "not necessarily adjacent"? How could the two X's possibly be adjacent, if there is a Y between them?

Comment: @bof it means that the Y's need not be beside each other, but can be arranged for example: XYXYX. As a result, like what RobertZ and Hagen von Eitzen suggested below, it leads to 3 possible cases: XXYYX, XYYXX, XYXYX. 

P.s. I'm sorry but the question was stated as such as quoted from my textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\binom{11}{5}$ is the number of ways to select $5$ positions among $11$.
In the five selected positions, we put the letters $\{X,X,X,Y,Y\}$ in one if these $3$ possible ordered arrangements: "XXYYX", "XYYXX" and "XYXYX" (every $Y$ lies between two $X$'s).
In the remaining $6$ positions, we put the 6 distinct letters $\{A, B, C,D, E, F\}$ in $6!$ ways. Therefore the total number is
$$\binom{11}{5}\cdot 3\cdot 6!.$$

Comment: Hmm.. correct me if I am wrong, but the ways to select 5 positions among 11 does not factor in how $X, X, X, Y, Y$ are arranged right?

Comment: @Stoner No, with $\binom{11}{5}$ you are selecting 5 positions and not what you are going to put in those positions.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the help and for clarifying my conceptual errors!

Answer (score 1):

There are $11\choose 5$ ways to pick the positions of the $X$s and $Y$s (without deciding which of them is $X$ and which is $Y$).
The sequence of the $X$s and $Y$s alone must begin with $X$ and end with $X$. This leaves $3\choose 1$ ways to arrange the remaining three letters (one $X$ and two $Y$). Finally, there are $6!$ ways to arrange the six different letters $A,\ldots, F$ in the remaining six positions.

Comment: Similar to what I have commented above, am I right to say that the ways to select 5 positions among 11 does not factor in how $X,X,X,Y,Y$ are arranged?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I understand how I should approach this question now. I'll be marking @RobertZ 's answer as the solution as he posted a bit earlier and both answers are similar. Thanks again! :)